# Docker NiFi not connect with other network.

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I set up new remote server (ubuntu 16.04.3) to use NiFi on docker like following.

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sudo sh
$ docker pull apache/nifi
$ docker run --name nifi \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:latest
```

And I checked it using $ docker ps
[when I using $docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWBKI.png)

But I couldn't access using http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nifi
It was ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I checked 80 port, but it already opened

In this situation what should I do?

Comment: you are mapping docker container port to `8080`, so you have to use it in your url:  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/nifi

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the port number.
But I already tried xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/nifi but It didn't work.
Should I set up some requirement setting?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell NiFi which port & hostname it should be expecting as a part of new security checks, the easiest way to do this with docker is to pass in appropriate environment variables.
These are outlined in the [readme on the apache/nifi Dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/), but I shall paste them here for convenience:

```
docker run --name nifi \
-p 8080:8080 \
-d \
-e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='8080' \
-e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST='<your hostname or ip>' \
apache/nifi:latest
```